Nextflow pipeline: Accessing files from a channel when handling single and multiple inputs
Question:
I'm setting up a Nextflow pipeline that can process both single and multiple sets of input files. When processing a single set of files, I want to use command-line arguments like:
nextflow run main.nf --fasta sample.fasta --hmmdb database.hmm


For multiple sets of files, I prefer to provide them via a CSV file:
nextflow run main.nf --input samples.csv

The samples.csv file looks like this:
fasta,hmmdb
sample1.fasta,database1.hmm
sample2.fasta,database2.hmm

Current Workflow:
Here's the relevant part of my main.nf script:

workflow {

    main:

    if (params.input != null) {
        // Read input CSV file
        input_ch = Channel
            .fromPath(params.input)
            .splitCsv(header: true)
            .map { row -> tuple(
                    file(row.fasta),
                    file(row.hmmdb)
                )
            }
        input_ch.view()
    } else {
        // Use conventional arguments
        input_ch = Channel.of(
            tuple(
                file(params.fasta),
                file(params.hmmdb)
            )
        )
    }
    ch_versions = Channel.empty()

    // Launch the main pipeline workflow
    ACTUAL_PIPELINE(
        input_ch,
        ch_versions
    )
    ch_versions = ch_versions.mix(ACTUAL_PIPELINE.out.versions)

    //...
}

And the ACTUAL_PIPELINE workflow:
workflow ACTUAL_PIPELINE {

    take:
    ch_params     // Channel containing tuples of [fasta_file, hmmdb_file]
    ch_versions   // Channel for version information

    main:

    // Attempting to access the files from the channel
    collected = ch_params.collect()
    fasta = collected[0]
    hmmdb = collected[1]

    // Rest of the pipeline
    //...

}

Problem:
When I try to collect the contents of ch_params using collect(), and then access the files with collected[0] and collected[1], I encounter the following error:
ERROR ~ Unexpected error [StackOverflowError]



How can I properly access or iterate over the files from ch_params within the ACTUAL_PIPELINE workflow?
Is there a Nextflow-specific way to handle both single and multiple inputs efficiently without running into errors?

Thank you for your assistance!


How can I properly access or iterate over the files from ch_params
within the ACTUAL_PIPELINE workflow?

Note that ch_params is a channel, so calling the collect operator will also return a channel (specifically a value channel). It cannot be sliced like a List, which I think is the issue here. One solution might be to pass in a closure to transform each item before it is collected (assuming that is what is needed), for example:
workflow ACTUAL_PIPELINE {

   take:

   ch_params
   ch_versions

   main:

   fasta_ch = ch_params.collect { fasta, hmmdb -> fasta }
   hmmdb_ch = ch_params.collect { fasta, hmmdb -> hmmdb }

   ...
}


Is there a Nextflow-specific way to handle both single and multiple
inputs efficiently without running into errors?

Consider instead using the nf-schema plugin. It supports sample sheet formats including CSV, TSV, JSON and YAML. You would still need to handle your single and multiple inputs somehow (an if/else statement like what you have already is fine), but it lets you at least validate your inputs thereby reducing errors. Specifically, it lets you validate your input parameters against a pipeline schema, as well as validate the contents of your sample sheet against a sample sheet schema. From the docs:
include { validateParameters; paramsSummaryLog; samplesheetToList } from 'plugin/nf-schema'

// Validate input parameters
validateParameters()

// Print summary of supplied parameters
log.info paramsSummaryLog(workflow)

// Create a new channel of metadata from a sample sheet passed to the pipeline through the --input parameter
ch_input = Channel.fromList(samplesheetToList(params.input, "assets/schema_input.json"))

There's really no way to avoid errors, but the Nextflow extension for VS Code should help with syntax highlighting etc:
https://github.com/nextflow-io/vscode-language-nextflow

Thank you very much for the response. As a first step, I'm using hmmscan to query translated sequences against a HMM profile database. Since hmmscan is very I/O dependent, I thought that I could split the input sequences (e.g, each chromosome) into smaller files and let nextflow parallelize the whole process. So ideally, one instance of ACTUAL_PIPELINE workflow should be "initialized" for each row in the csv (one row = one chromosome). But I'm struggling a bit on how to correctly achieve that.

No worries @jllPons! Think of named workflows as a way to compose some number of related processes and business logic. They are useful if you need to re-use them (by including them under an alias), but it doesn't make sense to try to do this for n lines in your input channel. This is what channels are for. I think either just pass in your channel of sample inputs like you've done, or simply ignore the sub-workflow for now. Start be writing a process called hmmscan. The input block for this process might look like: tuple val(sample), path(fasta), path(hmmdb).

Consider also adding a column called 'sample' into your samples.csv (assuming you actually have multiple samples to process). But instead of now adding an option called --sample (for your single inputs), you may also want to consider removing the option for single inputs altogether. In my experience, single inputs are really only useful for testing purposes. In reality we have many samples to process, usually. If you only have multiple chromosomes belonging to a single sample, it might be simpler to include the process that splits the chromosomes in your workflow (if you haven't already).

Yes, I'll definitely just add a process that splits the chromosomes. For sure, I was not fully understanding the differences between workflows and processes. I will still keep the sample in csv option in mind. Thanks again!
